# SimpleSaml installation

Tags: php, file, configuration, simplesamlphp

I need a few advices about SimpleSaml installation.

In my company, i'm developping a website, and i want to add the Identity Federation. I chosed SimpleSaml. I'm on MAC Os. 
To resume :

1) In /var/ 
 - I put my folder simpleSaml

2) In /Users/Jules/Sites/
 - I have my website project named sos_informatique with simplesaml into.

3) I've done the configuration in http.conf

When i go to : `http://localhost/~Jules/test/simplesaml/`

I see the index of the simpleSaml folder with all the folders. 
whereas i should have seen the simpleSaml Configuration page :(

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by myself :)

For those who wants, it was about the simplesamlphp.log file. I changed the permissions on the simplesaml Directory (in /log) and after a few updates it works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found the solution, now i can access the page. But this is an : "Unhandled exception".
In the error.log they said :

```
SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Error 2 - touch(): Unable to create file /var/log/simplesaml/simplesamlphp.log because Permission denied, referer: http://localhost/~Jules/test/simplesaml/www/module.php/core/as_login.php?AuthId=Oxylane-sp&ReturnTo=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F%7EJules%2Ftest%2F
```

Which file do i have to modify please ?

EDIT : 
The error page looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiRrl.jpg)